# Android development: 1st touch = TextView1, 2nd touch = TextView2 etc

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

I need some help with with my android-program. I need to make few TextViews to appear on each touch. 1st touch = TextView1, 2nd touch = TextView2 etc. I tried to make it with ACTION_POINTER_DOWN after ACTION_DOWN, but it shows all Text Views in one touch.

```
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

 boolean inTouch = false;

        int actionMask = event.getActionMasked();
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
         int downPI = 0;
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // 1st touch
                inTouch = true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: // next touches
                        downPI = pointerCount;
                        switch (downPI) {
                            case 0:
                                tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                tv3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                break;

                        }
                        break;


        }

            return false;
```

Comment: You have to check in `ACTION_UP` because the `ACTION_DOWN` gets triggered very often

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below solution:-

Just add below line (define variable) above `onCreate()`:-

```
int downPI = 0;
```

And comment below code like that in `onTouch`:-

```
//                downPI = pointerCount;
```

And Increment before `return false;` like:-

```
if(downPI < 3)
        downPI++;

    return false;
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I just thought that pointerCount should change it`s value with each touch

Comment: No problem. Sometimes, alternative way is better in coding.